# Django monkey patching model with method seems to work correctly as instance method - am I missing something?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 3.2 and I am having to monkey patch a model, based on some conditional logic.

#### myapp/models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # fields ...
    # methods ...
    pass
```

#### in console

```
from myapp.models import Foo

def something(obj):
    return obj.id

# Monkey patching the class (model)

setattr(Foo, 'mysomething', something)

# Fetch an instance form db

f = Foo.objects.all().first()

f.mysomething()

# return 1 (correct)
```

My surprise is the fact that the something method is not accepting an argument, and instead, seems to be using the argument specified in the definition (obj) as a synonym for `self` - and therefore, the method is acting like an **instance method**.

Can anyone explain the technical reason why this is happening - and is this documented (and therefore consistent) behaviour I can rely on in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected and consistent behaviour. Doing this:

```
setattr(Foo, 'mysomething', something)
```

is functionally equivalent to doing this (just that you do it later, rather than when the class is defined):

```
class Foo:

    def mysomething(self):
        return something(self)
```

In Python, defining a method on a class without any decorator implies it is an instance method - i.e, that the first argument to the method will be the instance itself. Defining a method via `setattr` does not change this fact - it's just a less obvious way of doing it.

Consider this alternative, which illustrates the point:

```
# Now we wrap `something` in `staticmethod`
setattr(Foo, 'mysomething', staticmethod(something))
```

is equivalent to:

```
class Foo:

    @staticmethod
    def mysomething():
        return something()
```

Now, because it's been added as a static method, it will not be passed an instance of the class when you call it, and you'll get an error if you try calling `Foo().mysomething()`:

```
TypeError: something() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'
```